# Existence of the derivative of functionals of Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes

Let $v(x, t) = \mathbb E [f(x + W_t)]$ with a Brownian motion $W$. Then, Malliavin calculus leads to the sensitivity in $x$:
$$\partial_x v(x, t) = \frac{1}{t} \mathbb E [ f(x + W_t) W_t ].$$
I am interested in $u'(x)$ with $u$ defined by
$$u(x) = \mathbb E \int_0^T f(x + W_t) dt$$
for some function $f$. First we can write
$$u'(x) = \int_0^T \partial_x v(x, t) dt = \int_0^T \frac{1}{t} \mathbb E[f(x+W_t) W_t] dt$$
whenever the last integral exists.

[Question] What is the sufficient conditions on $f$ to have the $u'(x)$? In particular, when $f$ is not differentiable.

[Discussion] For instance, if $f$ is a constant, then $u'(x) = 0$; if $f$ is an identity, $u'(x) = T$. More generally, if $f'$ exists with polynomial growth, then $u'$ can be computed using the following alternative formula:
$$u'(x) = \mathbb E[ \int_0^T f'(x+W_t) dt].$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\vpi}{\varphi}\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}\newcommand{\Om}{\Omega}$The derivative $u'(x)$ exists and the equality
\begin{equation*}
    u'(x) =\int_0^T \frac{dt}t\, Ef(x+W_t)W_t \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
holds under very mild restrictions on $f$, just a bit stronger than the restrictions on $f$ needed for $u(x)$ itself to exist.

Indeed, suppose that the function $f\colon\R\to\R$ is Borel-measurable and such that
\begin{equation*}
    \int_0^T dt\, E|f(x+W_t)|<\infty; \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
for (2) to hold, it is enough that
\begin{equation*}
    |f(u)|\le Ce^{au^2}\quad\text{for some real $C$}, \\
    \text{some real $a<\frac1{2T}$, and all real $u$. } \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
Then, by Fubini's theorem,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    u(x)&=\int_0^T dt\,Ef(x + W_t) \\ 
    &=\int_0^T dt\int_\R dz\,f(x+z\sqrt t)\vpi(z) \\ 
    &=\int_0^T \frac{dt}{\sqrt t}\int_\R du\,f(u)\vpi\Big(\frac{x-u}{\sqrt t}\Big), 
\end{aligned}
\tag{4}
\end{equation*}
where $\vpi$ is the standard normal density.

Let us show that **condition (3) is sufficient for (1)** as well:

For all real $s$, let
\begin{equation*}
    \psi(s):=|\vpi'(s)|=|s|\vpi(s). 
\end{equation*}

Take any real $x$, any $\ep\in(0,T/2]$, and any
\begin{equation*}
    b\in\Big(a,\frac1{2T}\Big). \tag{4.5}
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\max\Big\{\psi\Big(\frac{y-u}{\sqrt t}\Big)\colon \ep\le t\le T,|y-x|\le1\Big\} 
    &\le C_{\ep,x,b,T}e^{-bu^2}, 
\end{aligned}
\tag{5}
\end{equation*}
where $C_{\ep,x,b,T}$ is a real number depending only on $\ep,x,b,T$, but not on $(t,u)$. Also,
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
&\int_\ep^T \frac{dt}{\sqrt t}\int_\R du\,
\Big|\partial_x\Big(f(u) \vpi\Big(\frac{x-u}{\sqrt t}\Big)\Big| \\ 
&=\int_\ep^T \frac{dt}t\int_\R du\,|f(u)|
    \psi\Big(\frac{x-u}{\sqrt t}\Big)   
\end{aligned} 
\tag{6}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{align*}
\int_\ep^T \frac{dt}t\int_\R du\,|f(u)|e^{-bu^2}<\infty, \tag{7}
\end{align*}
by (3) and (4.5).
Moreover, for $y\in[x-1,x+1]$, in view of (3) and the condition $\ep\in(0,T/2]$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\int_0^\ep \frac{dt}{\sqrt t}\int_\R du\,
\Big|\partial_y\Big(f(u) \vpi\Big(\frac{y-u}{\sqrt t}\Big)\Big| \\ 
&=\int_0^\ep \frac{dt}{\sqrt t}\,\int_\R dz\,\big|f(y+z\sqrt t)\big|\,|z|\,\vpi(z) \\ 
&\le CC_{x,T}\int_0^\ep \frac{dt}{\sqrt t}\,\int_\R dz\,e^{z^2/3}\vpi(z) \to0
\end{aligned}   
\tag{8}
\end{equation*}
as $\ep\downarrow0$, where $C_{x,T}$ is a real number depending only on $x,T$, but not on $\ep$.

Now we can write
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&   \int_0^T \frac{dt}t\, Ef(x+W_t)W_t \\ 
    =&\int_0^T \frac{dt}t\,\int_\R dz\,f(x+z\sqrt t)z\sqrt t\,\vpi(z) \\ 
    =&\int_0^T \frac{dt}t\int_\R du\,f(u)
    \frac{u-x}{\sqrt t}\vpi\Big(\frac{x-u}{\sqrt t}\Big) \\  
    =&\int_0^T \frac{dt}{\sqrt t}\int_\R du\,
    \partial_x\Big(f(u)
    \vpi\Big(\frac{x-u}{\sqrt t}\Big)\Big) \\  
    =&  \partial_x\int_0^T dt\int_\R du\,f(u)
\frac1{\sqrt t}\vpi\Big(\frac{x-u}{\sqrt t}\Big) \\    
    =&  \partial_x\int_0^T dt\, Ef(x+W_t)=u'(x);   
\end{aligned}
    \tag{9}
\end{equation*}
the interchange of the differentiation and integration (the fourth equality in display (9)) is possible by [Lemma 2.3](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-43/issue-5/Exact-Rosenthal-type-bounds/10.1214/14-AOP942.full), in view of (5), (6), (7), and (8). The penultimate equality in (9) holds by (4).

Thus, it is proved that (3) is sufficient for (1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess that $f$ is missing in the last expression of equation (8) after expectation operator. For the interchange of differentiation and integration, probably one can have the same condition you provided using Theorem 2 - P420 of the book "Partial Differential Equations" of Walter A. Strauss.

Comment: @kenneth : Thank you for spotting the typo; it is now fixed. Also, the proof is now simplified a bit.